# How exactly does BIP11 work, and how can it be used, particularly with/without P2SH?

Tags: multi-signature, p2sh

I'm trying to write a BIP11-compliant C# client that creates a 2 of 2 or 2 of 3 transaction.

I'm also trying to understand if a 3 of 3 transaction is supported as well.

[This example says they are creating a PS2H address](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/escrowexample.txt), but I'm unsure of exactly what script is being signed, and the meaning of the parameters "2" in addmultisigaddress, and what happens when addmultisigaddress is called.

I have researched the BIP, the [RPC documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list), and the forums.  I'm getting confused where if and when the P2SH is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you might be getting confused is that there are really two types of multisig, raw multisig and P2SH (pay-to-script-hash) multisig. P2SH multisig is basically just hashing the actual scriptPubKey desired and putting the scriptPubKey in the scriptSig. This stack exchange questions explains them in more detail: [What are the limits of m and n in m-of-n multisig addresses?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/what-are-the-limits-of-m-and-n-in-m-of-n-multisig-addresses/28092#28092).

> I'm also trying to understand if a 3 of 3 transaction is supported as well.

Yes, you can do m-of-3 multisig transactions with both raw multisig and P2SH multisig.

> the meaning of the parameters "2" in addmultisigaddress

The number provided is the m in the m-of-n. So if you want a 1-of-2, you do:

```
addmultisigaddress 1 '["1xy..", "1Jm..."]'
```

The BIP11 (accepted) proposal you mentioned just made raw multisig a standard type of transaction that is recognized and forwarded on by standard clients. BIP16 (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki) proposes the P2SH addresses, which allow for much shorter `scriptPubKey`s and support more types of multisig (e.g. 5-of-9, which you can't easily do with raw multisig because m-of-n multisigs with n > 3 are considered non-standard, as shown in the link in the first paragraph).

Comment: You have *m* and *n* mixed up.  [BIP11](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0011.mediawiki) uses m-of-n, where *m* is the *minimum* number of signatures and *n* is the *number* of keys.  (Or at least that's how I remember it.)

Comment: @DavidA.Harding, I update the post to use the standard notation.

Comment: @NickODell, which part do you think needs a clarification? I linked to [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/what-are-the-limits-of-m-and-n-in-m-of-n-multisig-addresses/28092#28092), which explains the size limits.

Comment: @StephenM347 `(e.g. 5-of-9, which you can't do with raw multisig because it would make the scriptPubKey too large).` I think that everything up to and including 20-of-20 multisig is valid. For example: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/49797406/0

Comment: @NickODell Gotcha, I'll clarify that it's an issue of standardness rather than validity.