# What is the maximum number of multisigaddresses you can create?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, multi-signature

I have created a few multisig addresses, and just tried to create a 2 of 3 address, but it returned with the 'AddCScript() failed' error.

What is the maximum number of m-sig addresses and where is this in the code? I'd like to know how to expand the limit for a test.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/23893/12983

Comment: Maybe it failed because the address you're creating already exists in the wallet?

Comment: You say, "the code", but you don't give us any idea what code you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what happened, the wallet was a massive size and the Write() function was failing.