# Can a block have multiple coinbase transactions? Also is there a limit to the number of signatures a multi-sig transaction has or requires?

Tags: mining-pools, protocol, coinbase-transaction, multi-signature

I am wondering if a block can be created with multiple coinbase transactions. The US government regulates mining pools that have control over the miner's wallets, so it would be fabulous if this could be circumvented by having multiple coinbase transactions to multi-sig wallets. Also is there a limit to the number of signatures that a multi-sig wallet can require?

Comment: This really is two separate questions, it would be best if you asked them individually.

Answer (score 1):

A block can only have one coinbase transaction. You could however send the reward+fees of the coinbase transaction to multiple addresses (of any type) just like any other transaction.

> is there a limit to the number of signatures that a multi-sig wallet can require?

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/28092/87716

Comment: Note that while the reward and fees can be spent like any other transaction, you must wait 100 blocks for the coinbase output to mature before spending it - this means it cannot be spent within the same block, or another 99 blocks following it.